# removing unicode from text in pandas

Tags: python, unicode, pandas

for one string, the code below removes unicode characters & new lines/carriage returns:

```
t = "We've\xe5\xcabeen invited to attend TEDxTeen, an independently organized TED event focused on encouraging youth to find \x89\xdb\xcfsimply irresistible\x89\xdb\x9d solutions to the complex issues we face every day.,"

t2 = t.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip()
import sys
sys.stdout.write(t2.strip('\n\r'))
```

but when I try to write a function in pandas to apply this to every cell of a column, it either fails because of an attribute error or I get a warning that a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

```
def clean_text(row):
    row= row["text"].decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore')#.strip()
    import sys
    sys.stdout.write(row.strip('\n\r'))
    return row
```

applied to my dataframe:

```
df["text"] = df.apply(clean_text, axis=1)
```

how can I apply this code to each element of a Series?

Comment: If all Unicode characters were removed, you'd end up with an empty string...

Comment: then how can I retain the text but get rid of characters like \xe5\xca and x89\xbd\x9d etc.?

Comment: Can you post a small example of a dataframe or Series where this fails?

Answer (score 12):

The problem seems like you are trying to access and alter `row['text']` and return the row itself when doing the apply function, when you do `apply` on a `DataFrame`, it's applying to each Series, so if changed to this should help:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([t for _ in range(5)], columns=['text'])

df 
                                                text
0  We've������been invited to attend TEDxTeen, an ind...
1  We've������been invited to attend TEDxTeen, an ind...
2  We've������been invited to attend TEDxTeen, an ind...
3  We've������been invited to attend TEDxTeen, an ind...
4  We've������been invited to attend TEDxTeen, an ind...
```

---

```
def clean_text(row):
    # return the list of decoded cell in the Series instead 
    return [r.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore') for r in row]

df['text'] = df.apply(clean_text)

df
                                                text
0  We'vebeen invited to attend TEDxTeen, an indep...
1  We'vebeen invited to attend TEDxTeen, an indep...
2  We'vebeen invited to attend TEDxTeen, an indep...
3  We'vebeen invited to attend TEDxTeen, an indep...
4  We'vebeen invited to attend TEDxTeen, an indep...
```

Alternatively you might use `lambda` as below, and directly apply to only `text` column:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: x.decode('unicode_escape').\
                                          encode('ascii', 'ignore').\
                                          strip())
```

Answer (score 8):

I actually can't reproduce your error: the following code runs for me without an error or warning.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([t,t,t],columns = ['text'])
df["text"] = df.apply(clean_text, axis=1)
```

If it helps, I think a more "pandas" way to approach this type of problem might be to use a regex with one of the `DataFrame.str` methods for example:

```
df["text"] =  df.text.str.replace('[^\x00-\x7F]','')
```

Comment: Python2 or Python3?   The OP didn't specify, and I think the default/assumption is still Python2 on StackOverflow, unless otherwise stated.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, where column_to_convert is the column you'd like to convert:

```
series = df['column_to_convert']
df["text"] =  [s.encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip()
               for s in series.str.decode('unicode_escape')]
```