# Replacing unicode from a text in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unicode, python-re

I have this dataframe:

```
>>> df
                   Temp
0   before 1.5° C after
1     before 2° C after
2    before 2°  C after
3  before 1.5°  C after
```

I apply this `replace` method:

```
newdf = df.replace(r'(?P<quote>\d[.]*[\d]*)(?u:00B0)\s+C', '(?P=quote)'r'C')
```

The dataframe remains unchanged.  However, I want it to look like this:

```
>>> newdf
               Temp
0 before 1.5C after
1   before 2C after
2   before 2C after
3 before 1.5C after
```

I've also tried `newdf = df.replace(r'°\s+','')` but that also doesn't change the dataframe.

**These other questions:**

- [removing unicode from text in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337402/removing-unicode-from-text-in-pandas) I don't want to remove all unicode characters, just this one when followed by zero or more spaces.
- [Replacing Unicode character in pandas Dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49465836/replacing-unicode-character-in-pandas-dataframe-column), but I need the regex for zero or more spaces.
- I can't just remove the unicode character first, because `°` is the indicator for where a change needs to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pattern `r"[^\d.C]"` to replace every thing except `int`, `decimal`, and `C`

**Ex:**

```
df["New"] = df["Temp"].str.replace(r"[^\d.C]", "")
#OR
df["New"] = df["Temp"].str.replace(r"(?<=\d)(°\s*)", "")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
      Temp   New
0   1.5° C  1.5C
1     2° C    2C
2     2° C    2C
3  1.5°  C  1.5C
```

Comment: Thanks my MWE was too minimal.  The second one works when the string I gave is in the context of the actual text.  I edited the question to make the MWE less minimal

Answer (score 0):

Another way; Just replace all `non digits` excluding `.`

```
 df["New"]=df.Temp.str.replace('[^\w\.]','')
```